# How can any user see HTML content editable contents from different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a template based site(like weebly) where users can change the text on the page just by clicking on it.

I have created the page having that functionality.But it just shows on the editor's browser as localStorage store the change on browser storage area.I want the changes made visible to every visitor on that page.

Here is the code

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>My Tasks</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   body{
    background:url(chobi.png);
   }
  </style>
  </head>

<body>
 <h1 id=hi contenteditable=true>My Tasks</h1>
 <p>Start typing in your list, and the browser will store it for you. When you reload it will still be here.</p>
 <ul id=myTasks contenteditable=true>
    <li></li>
 </ul>

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myTasks").blur(function() {
       localStorage.setItem('myTasData', this.innerHTML);
      });

      if ( localStorage.getItem('myTasData') ) {
        $("#myTasks").html(localStorage.getItem('myTasData')); 
      }

      $("#hi").blur(function() {
       localStorage.setItem('hiData', this.innerHTML);
      });

      if ( localStorage.getItem('hiData') ) {
       $("#hi").html(localStorage.getItem('hiData')); 
      }
    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `php` (a server side scripting language) or any other like `ASP` etc or a database MySQL (to store your data) **you cant do it with only client side scripting** :)
`PhP` and `MYSQL` are very easy

your php would be as

```
<?php

$content = #some cotent from database

echo "<div contenteditable='true'> ". $content."</div>" #now user can easily change the contant loaded from database

?>
```

and add one button then when user click on that button then all the changes will submit
on database then it will available for any one :)

Comment: but if i use php,I can't give them direct editing from the text.I might need to give them a text field to do that.And,I don't see any point of using Mysql here

Comment: @SalimKhan no u r wrong php works with html5 and php will use to load data from database only give a shot man :)

Comment: hey maq,I want the form of editing the text like weebly templates.Click on the text would allow user to change the form as if they are editing a .txt or docx file. Have u used that site before?

Comment: And,obviously I know how php and Mysql work with HTML,because I have built some site using PHP and Mysql

Comment: yup but u r not getting me :/

Comment: I'm sorry about that.Would you mind to clarify your point lil bit,please

Comment: @SalimKhan kindly check my updated ans if this help kindly upvote and accept if didnot then ping me back ;)

Comment: Thanks for your support,but this is not what I was looking for.Even though,this might be solution for others.So I would choose this one as an answer.